# Draw a shape using canvas in android studio without using custom view

Tags: android, android-canvas

My task is to draw a shape on second activity when user clicks a button. So I tried a following code, but it doesn't work.

I have referred lot of tutorials but all they did in another View. I didn't understand the View.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {
    Button draw;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        draw = findViewById(R.id.drawButton);
        draw.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        shape = dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("shape",shape);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),shapes.class);
        i.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Shapes.java

```
public class shapes extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shapes);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        Rect rec = new Rect();
        rec.top=100;
        rec.left=100;
        rec.bottom = rec.top + 100;
        rec.right = rec.left+ 100;
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawRect(rec,p);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When button click you are calling intent and it will create a new Activity. You can add a simple image view to the activity main layout and then you can set your canvas drawing as follows.

```
   ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, 
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);    
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Rect rec = new Rect();
    rec.top=0;
    rec.left=0;
    rec.bottom = rec.top + 100;
    rec.right = rec.left+ 100;
    canvas.drawRect(rec,paint);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I tried your code in onCreate method of second activity, When button is clicked the second activity is executed, no shapes are available in that activity

Comment: @ArunKumar I have edited the answer. Can you check now. It should work. Set the rectangle top and left to 0